# Configuration of open web analytics locally

Tags: php, joomla, wampserver, web-analytics, openwebanalytics

I try to run the [openwebanalytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/) software locally under wampserver and joomla using the instructions of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cj-d8HJYH2k).

I have created the db.

I have insert the owa file under the joomla site.

I type in my browser the path for the file

```
    http://localhost/openwebanalytics/owa/install.php
```

and press the start button.

In the next step I get this [image: error] but I can insert the data for the db.

I press the button for the next step and I get only warnings.

What could be possible wrong with the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a WARNING Message generated by PHP telling you that you are running OLD code which is using PHP core functions that have been deprecate. That means they are telling you that this fuction call will not exist in future versions of PHP and that you should change the scripts that use it if you ever want to upgrade PHP in the future.

In order to get this old code to run under this version of PHP, you can actually tell PHP not to generate these warnings.

Edit the php.ini, using the wampmanager menus ( to make sure you edit the correct file.

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

Look for this line

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

and chnage it to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

This is of course only a work around. The code will still need to be changed eventually, and this will only work for you until you upgrade to a version of PHP where this function has been completely removed.

You should contact the developer of the OWA addon to get it fixed or make sure you have the latest version of OWA.

Answer (score 0):

It is the version of php. I use php 5.5 and in order to run it without problem I have to use php 5.4 or later.